# Kotlin Tornadofx FilterList String out of range

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I am trying to learn tornadofx and i have come across an error i cant figure out how to solve sadly I am using the filterwhen fun and it works great however when i filter the data i get the error handler telling me i have a string out of range and it happens randomly often when i delete a char from the textfield i know the code is a mess :D

```
enter code hereclass CenterView : View("My View") {
private val ExcelHandler: ExcelController by inject()
private var content =  mutableListOf<Products>().observable()
private var rowcounter = SimpleIntegerProperty()
private var oktorun = SimpleBooleanProperty(true)
val table = TableView<Products>()
val data = SortedFilteredList(content).bindTo(table)
private var Accounts =  mutableListOf<String>().observable()




override val root = borderpane() {

    bottom{
        hbox(10) {

            style{
                padding = box(10.px)
                alignment = Pos.CENTER
            }


            button("Import"){
                addClass(Styles.btmDesign)
                style{
                   backgroundColor += Color.PURPLE
                    fontFamily = "Comic Sans MS"
                }
                useMaxWidth = true
                enableWhen(oktorun)
                action {
                    oktorun.value = false
                    runAsync {
                        ExcelHandler.readExcel("data/test.xlsx")
                    } ui { loadedText ->
                        content.isEmpty()
                        content.addAll(loadedText.observable())
                        rowcounter.value = loadedText.count()
                        Accounts.addAll(loadedText.map { it.Account }.toList().distinct()
                                .observable())
                        oktorun.value = true
                    }


                }
            }
            hbox{
                label("Rows ")
                {
                    style{
                        fontSize = 20.px
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD
                    }
                }
                label {
                    style{
                        fontSize = 20.px
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD
                        textFill = Color.GREEN
                    }
                    bind(rowcounter)
                }
            }

            textfield {
                promptText = "Filter"
                data.filterWhen(textProperty()) { query, item ->
                    item.Account!!.contains(query, ignoreCase = true)
                }


            }
    }


    left{
        listview(Accounts) {
            style{
                padding = box(20.px)
                fontSize = 20.px
                fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD
            }
        }
    }
    center{
        style{
            prefWidth = 100.px
            alignment = Pos.CENTER
            padding = box(20.px)
        }
        tableview(data) {
            isEditable = true

            style{

                fontSize =20.px
                fontWeight = FontWeight.EXTRA_BOLD
            }
            column("External", Products::ExternalProperty)
            column("ItemRelation", Products::ItemRelationProperty)
            column("Account",Products::AccountProperty)
            column("Price", Products::AmmountProperty)
            column("currency", Products::ValutaProperty)
            column("Date", Products::DateProperty)
            column("Status", Products::StatusProperty)
            enableDirtyTracking()
            columnResizePolicy = SmartResize.POLICY
        }.multiSelect(true)
    }
    right {

    }

}

}
}
```

Thank you very much for your time!

the error is

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   3     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinTextRangeProvider.GetBoundingRectangles(WinTextRangeProvider.java:314)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: You might be hitting a JavaFX bug here. Which version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: Hey thanks well currently i am using 8 and target jvm 1.8 i am kinda new to java aswell  :O

Comment: Yes I am using NetBeans with JDK 8 and when i used 10 for a bit i had some problems with apache poi where i got  java Illegal reflection warning so i just switched to 8 hm

Comment: Okay now i just tried using java 10 and it compiles fine but i cant launch it :owell i dont know at this point

Comment: TornadoFX is only compatible with JDK8, and you need to use the latest version available. Please confirm, and also make sure your code sample is actually runnable, ie. includes all the classes you reference.

Comment: ah okay sure I will go and check all my dependencys versions :) On a side note what build system do you prefer Gradle or Maven? I am using Maven atm

Comment: Hey okay so now i just made sure i am using all the latest stable versions in my maven file but i just found out that the problem only occurre when i delete quickly in the textfield that filters my data but if i just "slowly" delete each char i have not reproduce the problem yet. do you by any chance know if i can limit that or at least ignore the error so it dossnt pop up ?

Comment: Well Well this is a problem with the textfield i just created one and when i enter text in it and hold down the key to delete the previous char the error pops up no bindings atall

Comment: Thanks for the bug fix it is working now!

Comment: This is weird now the problem is back :o and it is happening to a textfield with no bindings at all

Comment: Then post the complete, minimal code sample which exhibits this error.